# Does '( mean anything special in a Vim syntax region, specifically in pgsql.vim?

Tags: postgresql, vim, syntax

In this (quite popular) [Vim syntax file for PostgreSQL](https://github.com/exu/pgsql.vim/blob/master/syntax/pgsql.vim), there are thousands of lines following this pattern:

```
syn region pgsqlFunction start="abs'(" end=")" contains=ALL
syn region pgsqlFunction start="abstime'(" end=")" contains=ALL
syn region pgsqlFunction start="abstimeeq'(" end=")" contains=ALL
...
```

Using Vim 7.4, this doesn't work for me at all, unless I actually write `abs'(2.3)` (which is a syntax error for SQL). Removing the single quote before the opening paren fixes the problem.

Since this is a project on Github, I'd normally just fix the error and submit a pull request, but I'm hesitating because of how long this file has existed with the `'(` format. It has survived 29 revisions over three years on GitHub, and some other versions of the file can also be found [here](http://www.gunduz.org/postgresql/pgsql.vim) and [here](http://www.manniwood.com/vim_stuff/index.html). The pgsqlFunction region block makes up the vast bulk of the file, so it's hard to believe that nobody noticed it doesn't even work.

It's more likely that this is a problem on my end. Can I get this format to work, or is it really broken?

Comment: Relevant documentation: [`:syntax region`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-region), [syntax patterns](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-pattern), and [patterns](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern). From those documents, it seems that your question is the same as “does `'` or `'(` mean anything special in a [pattern](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern) (when [`magic`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27magic%27) is on)?”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a problem with the syntax file. The start and end attributes of syn-region are just magic (`:h magic`) regexes in vim regardless of user settings. (`:h syn-pattern`). The syntax files according to the documentation are supposed to be as portable as possible so your settings should not interfere with the output of the file.

Start just defines the start of the pattern. So in the case of `start="abs'("` it must start with `abs'(` which in vim regexes matches `abs'(` exactly.

So the syntax file is broken for `pgsqlFunction` highlighting.